# How to flip X and Y coordinates of a grid by GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinates

I have a grid, which has flipped X and Y coordinates (X is represented by Y values and Y is represented by X values). This results in grid being positioned in completely wrong place.

How can I flip the coordinates without loss of quality and doing by GDAL. Is it possible? If not, is there any other Linux library, that can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rasters are square (such as tiles), with equal numbers of rows and columns, and the format is writable, this is easy to do using a Python loop with the GDAL library:

```
from osgeo import gdal

fname = '/path/to/tile.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(fname, gdal.GA_Update)
assert ds.RasterXSize == ds.RasterYSize:

for iBand in range(ds.RasterCount):
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(iBand + 1)
    ar = band.ReadAsArray()
    band.WriteArray(ar.T)  # .T means transpose 2D array
ds = band = None  # save, close
```

---

However for non-square rasters, a more complicated approach is required to recreate a new raster:

- The raster driver would need to support `gdal.Create()` (check `driver = ds.GetDriver(); driver.GetMetadataItem('DCAP_CREATE')`)
- `Create()` requires the same pixel type, and may require several creation options
- Several data source objects would need to be copied over, such as the projection (`ds.GetProjection()`)
- There is potentially more metadata for each band, such as `band.GetNoDataValue()`
- The geotransform (`ds.GetGeoTransform()`) might need to be redefined, as it references the X and Y coordinate to the upper left corner. If the transpose axis is not the upper left corner, then it would need to be calculated.